# Problema con setInterval. Simon Says

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema con el *SimonSays*:

Quiero hacer el **efecto** de que se coloree el cuadro de un color destacado que tienes que pulsar, y al segundo se vuelva a un color más apagado. A través de cambiar `id` con el `setAttribute`. Consigo destacarlo (cambiar `id` a destacado), pero a la hora de intentar devolverlo al `id` original, me ignora por completo.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    boton = document.querySelector('input[name=enviar]');

    boton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      var orden = 0;
      var posiciones = generaPosicion();
      resaltarColores(posiciones);

    })
}

function generaPosicion(valor) {
  var numColores = valor || 4;
  var arrPos = new Array();
  var numeroFijoColores = 3;
  for(var i=0, fin = numColores; i<fin;i++){
    arrPos[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * numeroFijoColores );
  }
  return arrPos;
}

function resaltarColores(posiciones) {
  console.log(posiciones)
  var idColoresA = Array('rojoDes', 'azulDes', 'amarilloDes', 'verdeDes');
  var botones = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  var x = 0, fin = posiciones.length;
  var auxPos;
    var idDes = setInterval(function() {
      devolverColorInicial(posiciones[x]);
      botones[posiciones[x]].setAttribute('id', idColoresA[posiciones[x]]);
      x++;
      if(!botones[posiciones[x]]){
          clearInterval(idDes);
          auxPos = x--;
          if(auxPos!=posiciones.length)
          devolverColorInicial(posiciones[auxPos]);
      }

  }, 1000);


}

function devolverColorInicial(posicionCosas) {

  var idColoresB = Array('rojo', 'azul', 'amarillo', 'verde');
  var botones = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  console.log(botones[posicionCosas]);
    console.log(idColoresB[posicionCosas]);

  botones[posicionCosas].setAttribute('id', idColoresB[posicionCosas]);
  console.log(botones[posicionCosas]);


}
```

```css
button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#col1, #col2, #col3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#col3{
  margin-top: 5%;
}
#rojo{
  background-color:rgb(231, 112, 112) ;
}
#azul{
  background-color: rgb(127, 113, 233);
}
#amarillo{
  background-color: rgb(227, 214, 129);
}
#verde{
  background-color: rgb(152, 231, 97);
}

#rojoDes{
  background-color:red;
}
#azulDes{
  background-color: blue;
}
#amarilloDes{
  background-color:yellow;
}
#verdeDes{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
  <script src="script/main.js"></script>
  <title>SimonSays</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="col1">
    <button id = "rojo"></button>
    <button id = "azul"></button>
  </div>

  <div id="col2">
    <button id = "amarillo"></button>
    <button id = "verde"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="col3">  <input type="button" name="enviar" value="Inicio"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function devolverColorInicial(posicionCosas, chivato) {
setTimeout(function() {
var idColores = Array('rojo', 'azul', 'amarillo', 'verde');
var botones = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
botones[posicionCosas].setAttribute('id', idColores[posicionCosas]);
},1000);

}
```

Como apunte, añadir que aumenté también el tiempo de intervalo a 2000

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está en esta parte del código:

```
devolverColorInicial(posiciones[x])
```

Básicamente primero "apagas" el botón, pero luego enciendes de nuevo el mismo botón que esta en la posición "x" del arreglo (en esta linea).

```
botones[posiciones[x]].setAttribute('id', idColoresA[posiciones[x]]);
```

Si colocas un -1 a la variable "x" puedes lograr un efecto como el que quieres (o al menos eso creo), ya que apagaría el de la posición anterior (x-1) y encendería el de la posición "x". Esto podría resolver el problema que comentas:

```
var idDes = setInterval(function() {
  if(x > 0){
     devolverColorInicial(posiciones[x-1]);
  }
botones[posiciones[x]].setAttribute('id', idColoresA[posiciones[x]]);
x++;
if(!botones[posiciones[x]]){
//Esta linea apaga el ultimo color al pasar 1 segundo.
setTimeout(devolverColorInicial, 1000, posiciones[x-1]);
   clearInterval(idDes);
      auxPos = x--;
      if(auxPos!=posiciones.length)
      devolverColorInicial(posiciones[auxPos]);
  }
}, 1000);
```

También puedes crear una variable para contar los segundos del intervalo.
Luego en cada segundo verificar con una condición si el contador es par o impar, si es par enciendes el botón, si es impar lo apagas e incrementas la variable "x" para encender con el siguiente botón y también incrementas la variable de contador cada segundo.